# What do weight and durability do in Tony Hawk's Pro Skater 2?

Tags: tony-hawks-pro-skater-2

In the Skate Shop in Tony Hawk 2 on PS1, decks have four different stats: Weight, Speed, Durability, and Turning. Speed and Turning seem self-explanatory, but what do Weight and Durability do?

[image: board stats in skate shop]

Comment: Wow, this is going back a looooong way. Did boards break if you performed a boardslide for too long? I can't remember any longer... perhaps time to dig out the PS1?

Comment: Might the weight stat affect how high you go off a jump?

Comment: Wow, my guess would be this is related to Manualing and Grinding meters. But, I have no idea, and there appears to be no answer on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Based off this article https://www.ign.com/faqs/2002/tony-hawks-pro-skater-2-walkthroughfaq-367640 I'm not so sure that weight and/or durability affect anything. My thinking is that they are just stats that are there to make the "decks" feel unique.

From the article:

> The Skate Shop is used to upgrade a character's skateboard.  In the Skate Shop you can modify your deck and trucks.  The trucks affect the turning 
>   statistic and the deck affects the weight, speed and durability statistics. Turning, weight, speed and durability all have a minimum value of 1 and a maximum value of 5.
>
> [...] There are three kinds of trucks.  They affect a skater's turning ability. All three different kinds of trucks are available at the start and are free. Tight trucks have a turning value of 1.  Medium trucks have a turning value of 3.  Loose trucks have a turning value of 5.

Comment: Does that mean speed doesn’t do anything either?

Comment: Not sure. Weight and durability just seem really abstract, like they're just there to make each deck seem different. Speed and turning would easily noticeable in game I would think. Weight might affect jump height, as someone else mentioned. Durability just seems weird, since the decks don't need to be repaired as far as I can tell.

Comment: It's always possible that they relate to a feature that they meant to finish, but had to cut to get the game out the door. Maybe boards were meant to be destructible :)